# How did Tinkerbell become Peter Pan's personal pixie pal and magical guardian?

Tags: peter-pan, tinker-bell

This question could have several different answers, depending on the version of *Peter Pan* used, so multiple answers are acceptable. Any canon sources [the original Barry novels and subsequent works] would be most appreciated. Basically:

1. **How did Peter and Tinkerbell become a team?**
2. **Is Tink attached to Peter because she *formed* from him?**
3. **Is Tink perhaps Peter's "Familiar" in some way, or is she completely autonomous and only chooses to remain with him?**

The generally accepted origin lore of fairies is that when a baby laughs for the first time, the spirit of that laugh flies off and takes physical form to become a fairy. If this is the case, then Tinkerbell's attachment to Peter *could* be explained by her being the Fairy that developed from *his* first laugh, but I know no sources that quote this.

In **Disney,** Tink is just "with" Peter from the start, and her stand alone movies seem to show that not only does she pre-date Peter, but she has a twin sister.

In the film **Hook** Peter somehow managed to "run away" in his pram, and was *found* by Tinkerbell, who taught him how to fly and took him to Neverland.

The Fox Kids' series **Peter Pan & the Pirates** show Tink as being somewhat romantically interested in, and thus *highly* protective of Peter, as well as being one of only two spirits [including Wendy] that can emotionally touch him on the deepest level. IT was implied in one episode by Queen Tatiana of the Fairy kingdom that, while not attach, Peter has been a "friend of the fairies" and somewhat raised on their ways for untold years.

And there are certainly other versions, but none that I know of definitely show a more magical connection.

Comment: I feel this should pick a single universe for the question. It is not asking for all the various ways the team formed, until it does. Try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4):

Disney has created several Tinkerbell movies as part of the [*Disney Fairies* series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney_Fairies), which focus on her life before Peter Pan.

These do ***not*** explicitly answer your questions regarding Tinkerbell's 'parent' child (the first movie does not identify the baby whose laugh formed Tinkerbell), but it does show that faeries have a society of their own, and roles within it.

Having watched the majority of the series, I can confidently state that the fairies do not seem to have any drive to attach to the child who birthed them.  They are fully sapient beings with their own thoughts, feelings, and drives.

Thus we can surmise with confidence that Tinkerbell is not a 'Familiar' to Peter, and there is no reason to suspect that he laughed the laugh that birthed her.

So the answers to your second and third question are "**There's no reason to believe so**" and "**No**", respectively.

Comment: The answer to the second question is a "certainly not" - Peter himself refutes it in the novel - "He had to translate. 'She is not very polite. She says you are a great ugly girl, and that she is my fairy.'
He tried to argue with Tink. 'You know you can't be my fairy, Tink, because I am a gentleman and you are a lady.'"

Comment: @Showsni - Unless you can demonstrate that the sex of the baby always matches the sex of the resulting fairy, that is nothing but Peter's opinion.